# Comparing two files based on size

Tags: linux, grep, centos, ls, du

I am facing difficulty in extracting the unique files of different sizes.

Question: Inside a directory few files are present, suppose 2 files of 2 mb, 4 files of 4 mb and 3 files of 6 mb.

Now, we need to run a script which will check all the files and their sizes and will print only first occurrence of different sized file.

Eg. if it reads a file f1 and its is a 2mb file , it will do ls -al of f1

Next time if it gets a file of 2 mb size , it will skip it

and hence in this case it will print only 3 file with different size of 2 mb 4 mb and 6 mb.

```
[sumit.gupta@abc ~]$ ll mytestfolder/
total 38972
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 2097152 Jan  6 23:26 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 2097152 Jan  6 23:27 f2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 4194304 Jan  6 23:28 f3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 4194304 Jan  6 23:28 f4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 6291456 Jan  6 23:28 f5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 6291456 Jan  6 23:28 f6
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 4194304 Jan 13 11:11 f7
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 4194304 Jan 13 11:12 f8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 6291456 Jan 13 11:12 f9
```

I am trying below codes in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

source="/home/sumit.gupta/mytestfolder/"

ls -ltr /home/sumit.gupta/mytestfolder | cut -d ' ' -f 5,10 | \
    head -n -1 > /tmp/abc.txt
ls -ltr /home/sumit.gupta/mytestfolder | cut -d ' ' -f5 | \
    uniq > /tmp/def.txt
grep -F -vf /tmp/def.txt /tmp/abc.txt > xyz.txt
```

Comment: Please add to the question your results and why don't they agree with your desires.

Comment: And don't [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) it adds problems when you aren't expecting them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here's the output:
[sumit.gupta@abc ~]$ sh input.sh
[sumit.gupta@abc ~]$
[sumit.gupta@abc ~]$ cat xyz.txt
[sumit.gupta@abc ~]$

I was getting blank result.

Thanks to @pax now the issue is solved.

Comment: This output should be added to question post itself, because it is part of problem's description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't get bitten by processing the output of `ls` (i.e., that you output lines consistently have the size in column 5 and don't do weird things like embed newlines in your file names), this is something that can be easily done with `awk`.

It processes the input only once and keeps a record of which sizes have already been seen so that it doesn't output subsequent files with the same size:

```
pax> ll mytestfolder/ | awk '!seen[$5] {print; seen[$5] = 1}'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 2097152 Jan  6 23:26 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 4194304 Jan  6 23:28 f3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sumit.gupta sumit.gupta 6291456 Jan  6 23:28 f5
```

Comment: u can create test files using: (just saying ;) )

dd if=/dev/zero of=/directory/f1 bs=1M count=2  

however, your logic works! Thanks a tonn for it. :)

Comment: @sumitgupta, thought of a better solution using *just* `awk` and a single pass of the data, something vital if it's coming through a pipeline as yours seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the file size using the "du -h directory_name/file_name" and compare it with the input file size.